# ドメイン文字列を、add_filterで削除しているが特定のAタグの中身だけ残したい。

Tags: php, html, wordpress

WEBページを制作しておりまして、feedlyのリンクを設置しようと思いました。
feedlyで取得したURLをアンカータグに設置したのですが、URLを正しく読み込んでくれません。

HTMLタグは

`<a class="RSS" href="https://feedly.com/i/subscription/feed/http://hogehoge.com/?feed=rss2">hoge</a>`

といったURLですが
`https://feedly.com/i/subscription/feed//?feed=rss2`
といった感じで、`http://hogehoge.com`の部分が省略されてしまいます。
消えてしまうURLの部分をechoで出力しても結果は変わりませんでした。
そもそもが無理な話なのでしょうか？

### 原因の自己解決と追加の質問

原因がわかりました。
ドメインを表示させない処理を行っておりました。
この処理はできれば残しておきたいのですが……。
この処理を残したまま、フィード用のリンクのみドメインを出力させる方法はございますか？

```
<?php
class relative_URI {
    function relative_URI() {
        add_action('get_header', array(&$this, 'get_header'), 1);
        add_action('wp_footer', array(&$this, 'wp_footer'), 99999);
    }
    function replace_relative_URI($content) {
        $home_url = trailingslashit(get_home_url('/'));
        return str_replace($home_url, '/', $content);
    }
    function get_header(){
        ob_start(array(&$this, 'replace_relative_URI'));
    }
    function wp_footer(){
        ob_end_flush();
    }
}
new relative_URI();
?>
```

上記がドメインを表示させない処理となっております。

Comment: 「echoで出力しても」というのは、ベタ書きでダメだったので試してみたということでしょうか？ https://jsfiddle.net/b6jgff6z/

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
はい、ベタ書きで試しましたが、ダメでしたが、test.htmlファイルを作ってファイルをブラウザで表示すると出力されておりました。

Comment: でも何故 [`attachment_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/attachment_link/) [`wp_get_attachment_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_attachment_url/) フィルタがそこに適用されるのでしょう。記載されているコードも「先頭から始まるホスト名だけを除去する」ように見えますし、原因は違うところにあるような・・・。

Comment: @unarist お返事ありがとうございます。
ソースを見せない状態で判断できないと思いますが、例えばどんな原因がありますか？
ちなみに動的に生成されるURLを、相対パスにしたい為このコードを記載しております。

Comment: そのフィルタは添付ファイル関連のURLに適用されるもののようなので、ベタ書きしたURLには適用されないと思ったのです。またその処理では `/i/subscription/feed/http://hogehoge.com/?feed=rss2` になるはずです。そのフィルタを除くと解決するのでしょうか？心当たりといっても、ひょっとしたらWPが不正なURLとして弾いたりしてるのだろうか、というぐらいしかないのですが。

Comment: @unarist お返事ありがとうございます。 
追記で記載しているコードを削除してみましたが、解決しませんね。。。。
他のWPサイトで同じアンカータグを作って確認したところ、正常に出力されています。

Comment: @unarist function.phpを再確認いたしました。どうやらunaristさんの言う通り、コードが違っていました。。。。
上記の「原因の自己解決と追加の質問」内のソースを書き直しましたので、ご確認いただければ幸いでございます。また、この処理はできれば残しておきたいのですが、残したまま上記URLだけ適応外にすることは可能でございますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WordPress で URL をすべて相対 URL にする方法 | dogmap.jp](http://dogmap.jp/2011/03/18/wordpress-relative-url/)

「get_header～wp_footerの間に出力された文字列に含まれる、サイトのホームURLを全て除去する」みたいなことになるので、確かに今回の問題が起きると思います。なかなか豪快な処理ですね・・・。

本文にベタ書きされたものは処理しなくていいのなら、 `="http://...` だけ置換するようにすれば、URLの先頭だけを消せます。

```
// 略

function replace_relative_URI($content) {
    $home_url = trailingslashit(get_home_url('/'));
    return str_replace('="'.$home_url, '="/', $content);
}

// 略
```

実行例 http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2xDBQR3qnPIhUi7i

---

恐らく上の方法で問題ないと思いますが、他の方法も参考までに載せておきます。

正規表現の[戻り読み言明](http://php.net/manual/ja/regexp.reference.assertions.php)で、スラッシュが前についてる時は消さないようにする方法。

```
function replace_relative_URI($content) {
    $home_url = trailingslashit(get_home_url('/'));
    $home_url_pattern = preg_quote($home_url, '#');
    return preg_replace('#(?<!/)'.$home_url_pattern.'#u', '/', $content);
}
```

実行例 http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7GGPiLwV6qx5bOpv

スラッシュに続くホームURLをURLエンコードする方法。ホームURL以降のスラッシュはエンコードされないのが微妙です（Feedlyでは動きます）。

```
function replace_relative_URI($content) {
    $home_url = trailingslashit(get_home_url('/'));
    $escaped_content = str_replace('/'.$home_url, '/'.urlencode($home_url), $content);
    return str_replace($home_url, '/', $escaped_content);
}
```

実行例 http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/PgZDbsogi1BnO2BN

Comment: わかりやすいソースをありがとうございます。素晴らしい！上記のソースで求めていた動作を行うことができました。ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0):

`delete_host_from_attachment_url`を以下のように変えてみて試してみて下さい。
おそらくこれでいけるかと思いますが、すみません自信ありません。

```
function delete_host_from_attachment_url($url) {
    $regixFeedly = '/^(http(s)?:\/\/feedly.*?)\/(http.+)$/';
    $regex = '/^http(s)?:\/\/[^\/\s]+(.*)$/';
    if (preg_match($regixFeedly, $url, $m)) {
        // http(s)://feedlyから始まるときに
        // httpが含まれていれば次のhttp以降の文字列をURLエンコードする
        $url = $m[1].'/'.urlencode($m[3]);
    } elseif (preg_match($regex, $url, $m)) {
        $url = $m[2];
    }
    return $url;
}
```

```
// https://feedlyから始まる場合
$url = 'https://feedly.co.jp/i/subscription/feed/http://hogehoge.com/?feed=rss2';
echo delete_host_from_attachment_url($url);
// 結果
https://feedly.co.jp/i/subscription/feed/http%3A%2F%2Fhogehoge.com%2F%3Ffeed%3Drss2
```

```
// https://feedlyから始まる場合2
$url = 'https://feedly.co.jp/i/subscription/feed/abc.png';
echo delete_host_from_attachment_url($url);
// 結果
/i/subscription/feed/abc.png
```

```
// http://fugafugaから始まる場合
$url = 'https://fugafuga.co.jp/i/subscription/feed/http%3A%2F%2Fhogehoge.com%2F%3Ffeed%3Drss2';
echo delete_host_from_attachment_url($url);
// 結果
/i/subscription/feed/http://hogehoge.com/?feed=rss2
```

```
// http://fugafugaから始まる場合2
$url = 'https://fugafuga.co.jp/i/subscription/feed/abc.png';
echo delete_host_from_attachment_url($url);
// 結果
/i/subscription/feed/abc.png
```

Comment: コメントいただきありがとうございます。
上記の方法を試させていただきましたが、エンコードが解けずに「このウェブページにアクセスできません」が表示されてしまいます。
https://feedly.co.jp/i/subscription/feed/http%3A%2F%2Fceleste-tokushima.com%2F%3Ffeed%3Drss2
このリンクのまま、ブラウザに送られているようです。

Comment: IE11で試してみましたが、
`<a class="RSS" href="http://feedly.com/i/subscription/feed/http://www.lifehacker.jp/index.xml">hoge</a>`でも`<a class="RSS" href="http://feedly.com/i/subscription/feed/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lifehacker.jp%2Findex.xml">hoge</a>`でもリンクは正常に動作します。

現状でどの時点で問題になっていますでしょうか？
１、ブラウザにレンダリングする時点で問題が起きている
２、リンクをクリックしたときに問題が起きている

１であれば取得しているリンク、レンダリングされているリンクを実際に問題のあるデータで示してもらえますか？
２であればどのブラウザで問題になっているかを示してもらえますか？

まずは問題の切り分けが必要だと思います。

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。多分、１の症状だと思います。ブラウザで要素の検証を行って確認いたしましたが、https://feedly.co.jp/i/subscription/feed/http%3A%2F%2Fhogehoge.com%2F%3Ffeed%3Drss2の表示のままでした。使用しているブラウザはGoogle Chromeです。

Comment: おそらくですが、`class relative_URI`もあまり関係が無いような気がします。実際に出力している部分のソースを載せたほうが良いような気がしますが...

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。class relative_URIこのコードを削除すれば表示されるようになりますので、このコードになにかしらの原因はあるのだと思います。